# CSS Firefox box-shadow and outline

Tags: css, firefox

I've added both outline and box-shadow to a div in my CSS code.
The div looks great on Chrome and IE but not in Firefox:
Chrome and IE:
http://i.phirune.com/csrjfyqoczob

FireFox:
http://i.phirune.com/4gsrrub3ww6e

The CSS code is as follows:

```
#container {
width:960px;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
margin-top:-10px;
background-color: #415475;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 25px 25px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 25px 25px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
box-shadow: 0 0 25px 25px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
outline:#000000 solid thick;
}
```

I have no idea how to fix this, any insight will be appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Why not use multiple box-shadows? Just separate your box-shadows by commas.

```
box-shadow:
    0px 0px 0px 1px #fff,
    0px 0px 0px 2px #606054,
    0px -1px 9px 1px rgba(119, 119, 119, 0.4);
```

You can add as many has your heart desires.

Comment: I tried it and it did not work. Even worst, I have no idea why adding shadows would fix such a bug??

Comment: Oh my god. You mean replacing the outline completely with shadows? Excellent indeed!

Comment: Box shadows can only appear under the element, whereas outline appears over top, which is usually the desired behaviour.

Comment: @aaaidan - That is not true. Notice he passed 4 arguments to the box shadow.  The 4th is for the "expand" value (which is optional).  This extends the box shadow outside of the element.  If you are referring to other items on the page, then you can also add a position relative to the element, to have it's shadow sit on top of adjacent HTML elements.

Comment: Yep, I'm familiar with the very handy "expand" value. It's been a while, but I think I was meaning that the shadow can't appear on top of the element itself (or its children). When you use outline, it always appears overlaid. This is useful if you want your outline to sit inside the bounds of the element, which looks tidier.

Answer (score 7):

This is a Firefox bug. You can only get around it. The ticket is still live, you may see at: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=480888

Comment: I just found this bug while writing a HTML5 calculator. I wanted to use `outline` to indicate keyboard focus and a box shadow to indicate mouse hover, but it fails badly in FF.

Answer (score 1):

```
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #00f;
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #00f;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #00f;
```

What browser versions are you attempting to support?  Modern browsers support css3 and you don't need to do the css hacks.

here's some css3 documentation for drop shadows: http://www.css3.info/preview/box-shadow/

Comment: I'm just looking to support modern browsers.

Comment: I would check out the css3 documentation then

Comment: I am going through the exact same problem... @PhiRune , can you explain what fixed it please ? And by the way, you should mark this question as answered :)