# how to outline a long span tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

a outline box as below is needed:

[image: red box]

The HTML code is:

```
<p>We <span>prefer questions that can be answered, not</span> just discussed.</p>
```

It is difficult to get the coordinate of the left-top point and right-bottom point of the outline box.

using:

```
outline: 2px red solid;
```

can only work in chrome, but failed in firefox. And also failed in chrome while the line-height of `<p>` is 300%.

Comment: What will be helpful here in future is `text-outline` which isn't supported yet

Comment: You're just messing with us aren't you @linuor ;)

Comment: ＠Carol McKay  I didn't mean any offense

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14085822/css-firefox-box-shadow-and-outline

Comment: @Carol McKay It doesn't work. Pay attention to the picture above. There is no outline between two lines of `<span>`

Answer (score 10):

Like so:

### CSS:

```
p {
    width: 220px;
}

span {
    outline: 2px red solid;
}
```

So you have the span around what you want, just put `outline` on it and done. Pretty simple uh? :D

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/463Nz/)

**Note:** As pointed out in the comments, this doesn't seem to work in Firefox. Looking into a solution now.

Comment: Wait what? What lines?

Comment: @Ruddy In firefox, there is a line. Not in Chrome

Comment: Ohh I see, it works in chrome so +1 :) my vote for your long awaited 2000

Comment: Oh, I see it doesn't work in firefox lol. I use chrome. Well pointed out. I will look into it.

Comment: It is not that simple (: please take a look at the picture carefully.

Comment: @linuor The picture is the same as my demo if you view it in chrome so it is that easy. But it doesn't work for Firefox, so I am looking into this. Will get back to you when I have something.

Comment: ＠Ruddy Your code works well in chrome. Waiting for your ideas. Thank you.

Comment: @linuor This is a very good question now we found this doesnt work with Firefox. I cannot find a fix, I will keep having ago at it but its not looking good. Note: Tested in IE and works.

Comment: @Ruddy Thank you for your help. PS: the outline will not work if the line-height of tag p is 300%.

Comment: @linuor Why would your `line-height` ever be `300%`?

Comment: @ZaheerAhmed the OP updated his question to include my answer.

Comment: @linuor I looked into this a bit more and I don't think its possible another way. This is the best we have for now, this seems to work of everything **but** Firefox. Annoying but for now I think that's the best we got. Sorry for the bad news. If you do find a way to do it please let me know as I would like to know how.

Comment: @Ruddy It is a pity. But i am still working on it. I will update this post if luckily to find the way out.

Answer (score -2):

If you know how to use CSS3, use it. Else, please insert the following within your html page.

```
<style type="text/css">
    span {
         border: 5px solid red;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: It is not that simple (: please take a look at the picture carefully.